# Magento backend print HTML instead of PDF

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to get Magento to print the invoice, orders an so on, in HTML templates, instead of PDF as it does by default.

I want it to print as it does from the frontend when customers are printing their orders.

So in short I want the same printing behaviour in the backend as on the frontend - HTML print instead of PDF.

Could this be done "easily" and could someone help me figure out how?

I would be utterly grateful!

Thanks and have a nice day!

Best regards
Mark Andreasen

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PAJ  free magento extension -

http://blog.gaiterjones.com/customiseable-printable-html-invoices-for-magento-free-magento-extension/